# how to configure ssh server on jenkins using jump host?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, ssh, tunneling

How to configure ssh server on jenkins using jump host?

Publish over SSH pluginprovide for a jump host option but not working.

I set up

```
Hostname : public ip (bastion server ip)
Username : ec2-user
```

in advance setting

```
Jump host: private ip (web application deployed server's private ip)
```

I opened ssh port on my was server. (open jenkins server ip connection)

and test connection result is here.

```
jenkins.plugins.publish_over.BapPublisherException: Failed to connect and initialize SSH connection. Message: [Failed to connect session for config [private]. Message [java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)]]
```

How to deploy web application to server which is in private subnet.

Answer (score 0):

There is a jenkins bug that seems to be still open:
https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-56119

I got the same error on testing configuration, but actual job is working over ssh jumphost.